# Multiple column index on inherited, non-overridden field

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, multiple-columns, code-first

I have a base class with some properties and behavior. This base class is extended/inherited by many other classes. Some of these classes are supposed to create an unique multiple column index on one of their own properties and on one property of the base class.

```
public class BaseClass
{ 
    long employeeId {get; set;}
    // and many other things...
}

public class Buzzword : BaseClass
{
    string Name {get;set;} // supposed to be unique for every employee
    // many other things...
}
```

What I want to to now is something like this, repeating my Buzzword class:

```
public class Buzzword : BaseClass
{
    [Index("IX_Buzzword_EmployeeId_Name", IsUnique = true, Order = 1]
    // black magic: inherited property of BaseClass
    [Index("IX_Buzzword_EmployeeId_Name", IsUnique = true, Order = 2]
    string Name {get;set;} // supposed to be unique for every employee
    // many other things...
}
```

How can I do this? Make employeeId virtual (therefore still implemented in all subclasses) and override it in the classes for multiple column index definition (and calls to the base implementation)?

Kind regards,
mate

Comment: Please read this and consider modifying your title to remove tags: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to skip using annotations and use `EntityTypeConfiguration` for your mappings if the base class contains columns that you need in multi-column indices.

So in your DbContext, you can do something like this:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<BuzzWord>().Property(b => b.EmployeeId).HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_Buzzword_EmployeeId_Name", 1)));
        modelBuilder.Entity<BuzzWord>().Property(b => b.Name).HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_Buzzword_EmployeeId_Name", 2)));
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Or, if you don't like polluting your DbContext with tons of mapping code, you can create a mapping classes and tell your context to load all of them:

```
public class BuzzWordMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<BuzzWord>
{
    public BuzzWordMapping()
    {
        Property(b => b.EmployeeId).HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_Buzzword_EmployeeId_Name", 1)));
        Property(b => b.Name).HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_Buzzword_EmployeeId_Name", 2)));
    }
}
```

Then your `OnModelCreating` would look like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //  This should include any mappings defined in the same assembly as the BuzzWordMapping class
        modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(typeof(BuzzWordMapping).Assembly);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);            
    }
```